# Tableau Dashboard custom view cannot save on Tableau Public server

Tags: tableau-api

I m using Tableau 2018.1.0(64-bit).  I have developed the custom dashboard which looks like this

[image]

but when I try to save it on server it changes to default version and which looks like this

[image]

I want to save the custom version on the server but every time I do it it changes to default version. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you viewing it in a browser on your desktop computer or on a mobile device?

Comment: I am viewing it in chrome on a computer... the same computer I used to create the dashboard